# I can't render a image for my pdf using jspdf

Tags: javascript, angular, image-processing, jspdf

I have a method that generate a pdf for me but i need to make a image (png ou jpg) for this pdf, i have already make a pdf but i can't do a image for my pdf, it shows a error.
I'm using angular and ionic, and i don't using html2canvas because doesn't support web components yet.

My method that generates a pdf:

```
generatePdf(){
   let imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,verylongbase64;'
   let doc = new jsPDF();
   let specialElementsHandlers = {
     '#editor': function(element, renderer){
       return true;
     }
   };

   let report = this.report.nativeElement;
   doc.fromHTML(report.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
    'width': 100,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementsHandlers
   });

   doc.text('my pdf', 15, 15);   
   doc.text(this.product.data, 15,290);
   doc.text(this.product.local, 80,290);
   doc.text(this.product.tag, 150, 290);
   //render and download pdf
   doc.save('teste.pdf');
   doc.setFontSize(40);
   doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
  }
```

Error in console:

```
ERROR Error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData
```

Comment: Your imgData might be corrupt, so can you please post the image data if possible

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy sorry, what is the image data?

Comment: i tried with an valid imageDate and it worked for me. `let imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,verylongbase64;'`

you are inserting a base64 string of the image, please check it

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy  the same error appears in console using this :(